# Javascript timer won't countdown to set time

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, timer

I'm having an issue with a timer i'm working on, what should happen is that the counter should countdown to a specific time which is defined by me. However for some reason the time i have defined is just ignored and it counts down to the next hour. What i am essentially trying to do is set a timer that will count down the time left to a number of specific times, so far i cannot even get it to work for one single defined time. I've attached a JsFiddle which contains all relevant code. Also would it possible to store the times in an array and have the timer count down to each defined time? Thanks in advance!

```js
var definedTime = new Date('Jan 31, 2015 05:00'); // military time to countdown TO

function ShowTimes() {

  var now = new Date();
  var hrs = definedTime.getHours() - now.getHours() - 1;
  if (hrs < 0) {
    hrs += 24;
  }
  var mins = 59 - now.getMinutes();
  var secs = 59 - now.getSeconds();
  var str = '';
  str = now.toString();
  str += '<br>Time until 05:00';
  str += '<br>'+hrs+' hours ' + mins + ' minutes ' + secs + ' seconds';
  document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML = str;

}

var _cntDown;

function StopTimes() {
  clearInterval(_cntDown);
}
```

```html
<body onload="_cntDown=setInterval('ShowTimes()',1000)">
  <div id="timer"></div>
  <button onclick="StopTimes()">Stop</button>
</body>
```

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by that?

Comment: I don't believe your date string ("00:00") is in a format that is being recognized. Try replacing with one of the accepted date string formats.

Comment: You're setting `hrs` from the defined time, but you're not doing anything with it in the countdown.

Comment: I've sorted that issue thank you, how would i go about defining multiple times? So for example defined times are 01:00 and 01:20, when the time reaches 00:50 the remaining time should be 10 minutes and when it reaches 01:00 it resets and repeats for the next defined time? Thank you guys.